# Sieve of Eratosthenes (reducing space complexity)

Tags: range, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes, space-complexity, number-theory

I wanted to generate prime numbers between two given numbers *‘a’* and *‘b’* (*b > a*). What I did was store Boolean values in an array of size *b-1* (that is for numbers *2* to *b*) and then I applied the sieve method.

Is there a better way, that reduces space complexity, if I don't need all prime numbers from *2* to *b*?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store all primes which are smaller of equal than the square root of b, then for each number between a and b check whether they are divisible by any of these numbers and they don't equal these numbers. So in our case the magic number is sqrt(b)

Comment: I am happy to help. If the answer is valid, you can accept it, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use segmented sieve of Eratosthenes. The basic idea is pretty simple.

In a typical sieve, we start with a large array of Booleans, all set to the same value. These represent odd numbers, starting from 3. We look at the first and see that it's true, so we add it to the list of prime numbers. Then we mark off every multiple of that number as not prime.

Now, the problem with this is that it's not very cache friendly. As we mark off the multiples of each number, we go through the entire array. Then when we reach the end, we start over from the beginning (which is no longer in the cache) and walk through the entire array again. Each time through the array, we read the entire array from main memory again.

For a segmented sieve, we do things a bit differently. We start by by finding only the primes up to the square root of the limit we care about. Then we use those to mark off primes in the main array. The difference here is the *order* in which we mark off primes. Instead of marking off *all* the multiples of three, then all the multiples of 5, and so on, we start by marking off the multiples of three for data that will fit in the cache. Then, instead of continuing on to more data in the array, we go back and mark off the multiples of five for the data that fits in the cache. Then the multiples of 7, and so on.

Then, when we've marked off all the multiples in that cache-sized chunk of data, we move on to the next cache-sized chunk of data. We start over with marking off multiples of 3 in this chunk, then multiples of 5, and so on until we've marked off all the multiples in this chunk. We continue that pattern until we've marked off all the non-prime numbers in all the chunks, and we're done.

So, given N primes below the square root of the limit we care about, a naive sieve will read the entire array of Booleans N times. By contrast, a segmented sieve will only read each chunk of the data once. Once a chunk of data is read from main memory, all the processing on that chunk is done before any more data is read from main memory.

The exact speed-up this gives will depend on the ratio of the speed of cache to the speed of main memory, the size of the array you're using vs. the size of the cache, and so on. Nonetheless, it is generally pretty substantial--for example, on my particular machine, looking for the primes up to 100 million, the segmented sieve has a speed advantage of about 10:1.

One thing you must remember, if you're using C++. A well-known issue with `std::vector<bool>` is Under C++98/03, `vector<bool>` was required to be a specialization that stored each Boolean as a single bit with some proxy trickery to get bool-like behavior. That requirement has since been lifted, but many libraries still include it.

With a non-segmented sieve, it's generally a useful trade-off. Although it requires a little extra CPU time to compute masks and such to modify only a single bit at a time, it saves enough bandwidth to main memory to more than compensate.

With a segmented sieve, bandwidth to main memory isn't nearly as large a factor, so using a `vector<char>` generally seems to give better results (at least with the compilers and processors I have handy).

Getting optimal performance from a segmented sieve does require knowledge of the size of your processor's cache, but getting it precisely correct isn't usually critical--if you assume the size is smaller than it really is, you won't necessarily get optimal use of your cache, but you usually won't lose a lot either.

Comment: A nice overview, but it conflates two different ideas. In the interest of clarity: what the OP primarily wants is a *windowed* sieve as indicated in the answer of Lajos Arpad. That is, only the range of interest (between a and b) is sieved, after procuring the sieve primes up to sqrt(b) with another sieve. What this article eloquently describes is a *segmented* sieve which processes whatever its range is in cache-sized increments; it can share some characteristics of windowed sieves but doesn't have to. Both ideas can be combined to give a segmented windowed sieve, if the target range is large

Comment: The point about `vector<char>` is important - bit-packed sieves require a lot of effort to make them faster than that, and `std::vector<bool>` is a completely lost cause anyway (except with fairly recent editions of highly optimising compilers like gcc and VC++). Bit-packing doesn't reduce space complexity but it can cut space requirement by a constant factor of 8 (straight bit-packing of an odds-only sieve) or about 16 (mod 30 wheel). However, they require fearsomely complex code if they are to be faster than `vector<char>` which still gives the best bang for buck overall (simple and fast).